# Thread got stuck on first join

Tags: python, python-3.x, multithreading

I'm using multithreading and I have 5 threads in total and when doing `t.join()`, only one thread get ended and the rest keeps going. Anyone knows why?

My script:

```py
if __name__ == "__main__":
    args.debug = True
    for x in args.list:
        args.threads.append(threading.Thread(target=RD.stream, args=(x,)))
    args.threads.append(threading.Thread(target=RD.subs_stream))
    args.threads.append(threading.Thread(target=TW.stream))
    args.threads.append(threading.Thread(target=pooling_stream))
    start_threads()
    while True:
        time.sleep(1)
        if not args.update:
            print("Update")
        else:
            for i in range(len(args.threads)):
                try:
                    if args.threads[i].is_alive():
                        print(f"before Stopped Thread {str(args.threads[i])}")
                        args.threads[i].join()
                        print(f"after Stopped Thread {str(args.threads[i])}")
                    else:
                        print(i)
                except Exception as e:
                    print(e)
```

Output is:

```
Started Thread <Thread(Thread-1, initial)>
Started Thread <Thread(Thread-2, initial)>
Started Thread <Thread(Thread-3, initial)>
Started Thread <Thread(Thread-4, initial)>
Started Thread <Thread(Thread-5, initial)>
Update
Update
Update
Update
before Stopped Thread <Thread(Thread-1, started 19972)>
```

Comment: It will depend on the functions being called in the threads. Do they return? If not, you'll wait forever.

Comment: They don't return, it's a stream that runs forever. any suggestions on what would be easy to implement? @tdelaney

Comment: Are you looking for a way to terminate the threads? These streams likely have some method call to terminate/close them. The threads will be waiting for a receive or whatever, but if you call those terminate methods, the thread functions will likely get an error and you can use that to return out of the thread. If you don't care about a clean close, you could mark the threads as `daemon` _before_ you start them. Then just exit the program without ever doing a join.

Comment: Could you try to write an example on the script I posted? Maybe I could make it work with `daemon` @tdelaney

Comment: I can't write an example for closing the streams because I don't know what that API is. I can write up the hard exit case.

Comment: I will still try it, thanks waiting for your reply @tdelaney

Answer (score 1):

Your threads are calling functions that run forever, so the join will wait forever. If these functions have an API that lets you terminate the operation, then you can call them in the main thread. The threaded functions would have to be updated to handle the error and return. Note that by default, python will `join` threads on exit. You don't have to do that yourself unless you have a need to do something after the join (or want debug messages). As a rough example,

```
def stop_threads():
    # assuming these things have a "close" method to terminate them
    RD.stream.close()
    RD.subs_stream.close()
    etc...

if __name__ == "__main__":
    args.debug = True
    for x in args.list:
        args.threads.append(threading.Thread(target=RD.stream, args=(x,)))
    args.threads.append(threading.Thread(target=RD.subs_stream))
    args.threads.append(threading.Thread(target=TW.stream))
    args.threads.append(threading.Thread(target=pooling_stream))
    start_threads()
    while True:
        time.sleep(1)
        if not args.update:
            print("Update")
        else:
            stop_threads()
            break
```

If you don't care what happens to the threads and just want to exit once `update` is `True`, you can set the threads as "daemon" and then just exit the app. Normally, python keeps track of threads and does its own join when you terminate. The `daemon` flag tells python not to do that. Just exit.

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    args.debug = True
    for x in args.list:
        args.threads.append(threading.Thread(target=RD.stream, args=(x,)), daemon=True)
    args.threads.append(threading.Thread(target=RD.subs_stream), daemon=True)
    args.threads.append(threading.Thread(target=TW.stream), daemon=True)
    args.threads.append(threading.Thread(target=pooling_stream), daemon=True)
    start_threads()
    while True:
        time.sleep(1)
        if not args.update:
            print("Update")
        else:
            break
```